# Web template resource files: best practice

Tags: web-template, localization, resource-files

What is the proper recommended way to add resource files in Web Templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new "Import SharePoint Solution Package" from Installed templates project and select your web template that you import from sharepoint than add resource file to your solution:

- add Resource File project items to your project. If you do not have
  to localize code in addition to the markup, you can instead add
  Global Resources Files.
- Provide a name for the default language resource file.
- Give the localized resource files the same name appended with the
  language-specific culture ID. For example, MyAppResources.de-DE.resx
  for German and MyAppResources.ja-JP.resx for Japanese.
- Set the Deployment Type property of each resource file to
  AppGlobalResource. This causes the resource files to deploy to the
  App_GlobalResources folder, where they are available to all ASPX
  pages and controls in the solution. The App_GlobalResources folder is
  located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\\App_GlobalResources.
  Then replace all string in all artifacts(list, modules, pages..) to use your new resource file. For more details check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696750.aspx).